# Converting column of dataframe based on scaling factor from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a column `length` (numeric) and another column units (string). For example,

```
df2convert =
length    units
1.0       "m"       # meters
1.4       "in"      # inches
0.5       "km"      # kilometers
....
```

I have another dataframe that maps all the units to meters. For example

```
units2meters:
units   scaling
"m"     1.0
"in"    0.0254
"km"    1000
```

I want to convert everything in `df2convert` to meters.

Currently, I do it without joining/merging the 2 dataframes.
I convert `units2meters` to a `dict` with key as `units` and value as `scaling` and then pass in `df2.convert.units` as a key into the hash table.

Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether or not this is the method you're already using, but I would use:

```
lookup = units2meters.set_index("units")["scaling"]
df2convert["length"] * df2convert["units"].map(lookup)
```

```
0      1.00000
1      0.03556
2    500.00000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I do it without `map`. Why is setting the index equal to `units` needed here?

Comment: Have a look at the map docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

`Series.map` expects some sort of key-value mapping that can be used to transform the data in the series. By setting `units` to the index, the Series passed to Series.map acts as a key-value mapping with the keys (the units) being the index

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df2convert = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "length":[1.0, 1.4, 0.5],
    "units":["m","in","km"]})

units2meters = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "units":["m","km","in"],
    "scaling":[1.0, 1000, 0.0254]})

merge = pd.merge(units2meters, df2convert, on="units")
merge["result"] = merge["length"] * merge["scaling"]
```